# cancel booking option in laravel-8 booking system

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, cancel-button

I need help adding Cancel Option for an existing booking,
I have $service, booking_code, min_before_cancel, start_date, and status.
I want to have the button active ONLY if min_before_cancel !=0 otherwise booking is non-refundable.
and the button cancel should be active still time limit (min_before_cancel) if the start_date and today = or less than min_before_cancel the button should disappear.

I have added this in the View

```
@if ($service =booking->service->time_before_cancel != 0 && \Carbon\Carbon::now() >$booking->start_date->subDays($service->min_before_cancel))
<button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
@endif
```

and in the BookingController the following function:

```
public function cancel($code)
{
// Retrieve the booking from the database
$booking = Booking::find($code);

 // Update the booking status
$booking->status = 'cancelled';
$booking->save();

 // Return a success message to the user
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Your booking has been canceled.');
}
public function showCancelOption($bookingCode)
{
// Retrieve the booking from the database
$booking = Booking::where('booking_code', $bookingCode)->first();

// Retrieve the service associated with the booking
$service = $booking->service;

// Calculate the difference in days between the start date and today
$startDate = new Carbon($booking->start_date);
$today = Carbon::now();
$diffInDays = $startDate->diffInDays($today);

}
}
```

in the Route:

```
 Route::post('/booking/{code}/cancel', 'BookingController@cancel')->name('booking.cancel');
```

and new cancel.blade under the booking folder.

Booking Modl

```
class Boat extends Bookable
{
use Notifiable;
use SoftDeletes;
use CapturesService;

protected $table = 'bravo_boats';
public $type = 'boat';
public $checkout_booking_detail_file       = 'Boat::frontend/booking/detail';
public $checkout_booking_detail_modal_file = 'Boat::frontend/booking/detail-modal';
public $set_paid_modal_file                = 'Boat::frontend/booking/set-paid-modal';
public $email_new_booking_file             = 'Boat::emails.new_booking_detail';
public $availabilityClass = BoatDate::class;

protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'content',
    'category_id',
    'cancellation_id',
    'style_id',
    'capt_id',
    'health_id',
    'status',
    'manufacturer',
    'reference',
    'crew',
    'model',
    'faqs'
];
protected $slugField     = 'slug';
protected $slugFromField = 'title';
protected $seo_type = 'boat';

protected $casts = [
    'faqs'  => 'array',
    'specs'  => 'array',
    'category'=>'array',
    'cancellation'=>'array',
    'style'=>'array',
    'capt'=>'array',
    'health'=>'array',
    'extra_price'  => 'array',
    'service_fee'  => 'array',
    'price'=>'float',
    'sale_price'=>'float',
];
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: `$booking->start_date` is a String, not a `Carbon` instance. Do you have `protected $dates = ['start_date']` or `protected $casts = ['start_date' => 'date']` (or similar) in your `Booking` model?

Comment: Sidenote, moving all of that logic to a method or property of booking, like `public function canCancel() { return $service = $this->service->time_before_cancel != 0 && Carbon::now() > $this->start_date->subDays($service->min_before_cancel); }` would make more sense, so you can also add `if(!$booking->canCancel()) { return response()->json(['message' => 'Cannot cancel Booking'], 422); }` (or similar) in your Controller. Right now, you're relying on the button being disabled, but it's trivial to enable it via your browser's Console and cancel a booking that is otherwise not cancelable.

Comment: start_date  is not protected in the model

Comment: That's irrelevant; please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74777252/edit) and add your `Booking.php` model. I asked if you had `protected $casts` or `protected $dates` in your `Booking` model, not if `start_date` is protected ‍♂️

Comment: Many thanks, appreciate your help. Im still new to Laravel :)

Comment: yes protected $casts are there

Comment: No worries! So you do have `protected $casts = []` there, but you're missing `'start_date' => 'datetime'` (or `'date'`). Please check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting. If you've done it right, you can do `Booking::first()->start_date` inside of `php artisan tinker`, and it should show something like `lluminate\Support\Carbon @1668211200 ...` instead of `'2022-12-12'` (or similar)